# Change resource Working Time (add vacations) in MS Project (PWA)

Tags: office365, sharepoint, microsoft-project

Clicking on "Project" -> "Change Working Time" and choosing the resource, does not allow me to change the work time.

[image]

[image]

There's no dropdown arrow in Start and End columns... In MS Project Desktop app, I am logged in with my corporate account.

How to change resource working time for a PWA project?

Answer (score 1):

Among many ways, only the following worked:

1. If opened, close the Project Desktop app.
2. In PWA, open Enterprise Resource Pool.
   [image]
3. Check any resource and use "RESOURCES" -> "Open"
   [image]
4. "Yes"
   [image]
5. Double click the resource name
   [image]
6. "Change Working Time..."
   [image]
7. Add working time -> "OK" -> "OK"
   [image]
8. Exit the Desktop app clicking "Yes" to save the changes.
   [image]